# php framework nested method

Tags: php

How to use nested method while building framework in php ? Here `encrypt` and `sanitizeinput` both are method.

First, it will sanitize the input, then output will be encrypted. So I will try

```
$userData = [
    'Name'  =>  $this->encrypt(input('name')),
];
```

it will fetch error - undefined function input. I tried with

```
'Name'  =>  $this->encrypt()->input('name')
```

Obviously it will tell few arguments error.

But if input function is used removing encrypt, then it is fine.

Comment: Which framework do you use or is it your own? Would be nice if you'd show us the 'encrypt' function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally assigning multiple `this` works

```
$this->encrypt($this->input('name'));
```